# Selectize js - get all values of multiple sectize with same class

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I have a html page with multiple selects (made with selectize) that have same class "idPeople". When i click the button "search", i have to get all values of all the select (i've tried in my js file with jquery). But i get only the value of the first select ('select one'). Any suggestion?
HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- lib for jquery and selectize -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- select one -->
    <select class="idPeople">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    
    <!-- select two -->
    <select class="idPeople">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    ... other selects

    <button type="button" id="search">search</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS (in the head tag)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // init selectize
    $('.idPeople').selectize({
        sortField: 'text'
    });

    // get values of selects
    $( "#search" ).on('click',function() {
        var idpeople= $('.idPeople').val();
        console.log(idpeople);
    });

});
```

Comment: you could try $('.idPeople option') maybe

Comment: i dont see the link btween #search, click and idPeople?

Comment: "search" is the id of the button. In the js file, there is $( "#search" ).on('click'), that gets the values of the selects with class "idPeople" with the click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know selectize.js, but in pure jquery i'll do:

```
  $( "#search" ).on('click',function() {
   $(".idPeople option").each(function(){
     console.log($(this).val());
   });             
  });
```

or you could write:

```
  $( "#search" ).on('click',function() {
    $(".idPeople").find('option').each(function() {
     console.log($(this).val());
    });          
  });
```

or

```
var options = $(".idPeople option");

// Next, translate that into an array
var values = $.map(options, v => $(v).val())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with selectize it doesn't seem to work

Comment: see my answer modified..are you sure its not ok? its pure jquery...

Comment: how do you get the values distinctively? for select 1 and select 2?

Comment: hi Dave if i remember..!   the result of second selection is given following the first selection..there is a link between both selection